# Print lines number 2, 4, 8, 16... using awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I am trying to print every 2,4,8,16  and so on lines of a file with many rows and many columns.

This is what I tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN {N = 2}
 {  
  {if (NR  == N) {print; }}
  N = N*2
 }' infile > outfile
```

However, nothing is being written to the outfile.
What am I missing?

Here are the contents of a sample infile:

```
1 10
2 20
3 30
4 40
5 50
6 60
7 70
8 80
9 90
10 100
```

The expected output is

```
2 20
4 40
8 80
```

A file called outfile is created but with nothing in it.

Comment: I have added an example. Also, I don't have the time to read an entire book right now. I am trying to learn through examples on the web, and I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Given you don't know the language or the paradigm, how do you know which examples you find on the web to learn from? My experience has been that most examples online are way off base and IMHO you're going to learn a lot of bad habits very quickly and then spend years tripping over and consequently unlearning them before learning how to use awk the right way as you would from that book but YMMV I suppose so good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doubling your `N` for every record, but you only print something if `N` equals `NR` – which is never:

```
Line     Value of N
1        2
2        4
3        8
...
```

To fix it, you have to move the doubling of `N` so it only happens when `NR == N` is true:

```
awk -v n=2 'NR == n { print; n *= 2 }'
```

I've moved assigning the initial value outside of the program, used a lowercase `n` because of personal preference, and cleaned up the inside of the program: if the condition `NR == n` is true, then print the record and double `n`.

Running on the sample input:

```
$ awk -v n=2 'NR==n {print; n *= 2}' infile
2 20
4 40
8 80
```